# How to produce a symmetric layout for a large graph?

Tags: c++, boost, graph-algorithm, computational-geometry

I am using the [boost's Kamada-Kawai spring layout algorithm implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/graph/doc/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.html) to produce symmetric graph layouts. This works well for small graphs (up to a few hundred of vertices). However, it is too slow for larger graphs.

I looked inside the `boost` code to find what takes so much time and discovered that the algorithm begins by computing all-pairs shortest paths, which exhibits cubic complexity of course.

For my application, the graphs of interest consist of tens of thousands of vertices. The graphs are pretty sparse, so the number of edges is only by a small factor larger than the number of vertices.

Is there any trick or alternative that I can use to obtain symmetric layouts for such graphs?

Comment: The source code says that it uses Johnson all-pairs shortest path, which isn't cubic for a sparse graph. It might still be too slow.

Comment: @HansOlsson I stand corrected: for sparse graphs, it's `O(|V|^2 * log|V|)`. In any case, I verified that this computation is the bottleneck by running my code from `gdb`.